# MySQL: Can I Share enums?

Tags: mysql, enums

I have 3 similar tables, that would all have the same enum type field. Is there a way I can just reuse a single enum instead of creating each (duplicate) enum? Aware of BNF/don't want to use it/small project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You'll just have to keep track of this yourself. If it's something you change often, automate it.